# Simple question in probability

Tags: probability

please if we have continuous random variable

is $ P(X<=5) = P(X<5) $  ?
i've seen some soulition that they doesn't care about it , and some others put 
$  P(X<5) = P(X<=5-1 ) $

Comment: How is continuous distribution defined? How far have you come with your own answer to the question?

Comment: The $P(X<5)=P(X<=5-1)$ looks like a discrete probability distribution to me where $X$ can only take integer values. There was another comment stating the same a moment ago, but it vanished, else I'd have upvoted it instead of writing a new comment :(

Comment: @kushy Ah maybe i understand that we put $  P(X<5) = P(X<=5-1 ) $ if we are in discrete values and $ P(X<=5) = P(X<5) $  if we are in continuous values not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because $P(X=5)=0$. The reason you can find here: [Continuous probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution). If $\mu$ is a continuous probability distribution we have 
$$\mu(\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace) = 0 \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: yep exact @user144921 thanks

Comment: $  P(X<5) = P(X<=5-1 ) $ if we are in discrete values not ?

Comment: $P(X<5) = P(X\leq4 )$ is wrong in general for a  continuous random variable. kushy already explained his assumption.

Comment: ah exact , thanks